# compare 2 similar columns in 2 different dataframe and assign new data from dataframe 1 to dataframe 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 2 different dataframes with similar column data

Dataframe 1:

[image]

Dataframe 2:

[image]

I would like to compare those 2 similar columns and return data to dataframe 2. I went through few questions but none explain without loops. As I have data set of 10000 rows, I want to reduce the chance of looping and comparing each. Can someone suggest a method in pandas or numpy to do this?